# Binary Reject from Apple

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

Today I got binary rejected from apple and following message received from apple, please help me what should I do next?

> From Apple
>           2. 1 Performance: App Completeness
>
> **Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed**
>
> This type of app has been identified as one that may violate one or more of the following App Store Review Guidelines. Specifically, these types of apps often:
>   * 1.1.6 - Include false information, features, or misleading metadata.
>
> - 2.3.0 - Undergo significant concept changes after approval.
> - 2.3.1 - Have hidden or undocumented features, including hidden "switches" that redirect to a gambling or lottery website.
> - 3.1.1 - Use payment mechanisms other than in-app purchase to unlock features or functionality in the app.
> - 3.2.1 - Do not come from the financial institution performing the loan services.
> - 4.3.0 - Are a duplicate of another app or are conspicuously similar to another app.
> - 5.2.1 - Were not submitted by the legal entity that owns and is responsible for offering any services provided by the app.
> - 5.2.3 - Facilitate illegal file sharing or include the ability to save, convert, or download media from third party sources without explicit authorization from those sources.
> - 5.3.4 - Do not have the necessary licensing and permissions for all the locations where the app is used.
>
> Before we can continue with our review, please confirm that this app does not violate any of the above guidelines. You may reply to this message in Resolution Center or the App Review Information section in App Store Connect to verify this app’s compliance.   Given the tendency for apps of this type to violate the aforementioned guidelines, this review will take additional time. If at any time we discover that this app is in violation of these guidelines, the app will be rejected and removed from the App Store, and it may result in the termination of your Apple Developer Program account.  Should you choose to resubmit this app without confirming this app’s compliance, the next submission of this app will still require a longer review time. Additionally, this app will not be eligible for an expedited review until we have received your confirmation.

Comment: You should respond to apple as they have requested; Confirm that your app does not do those things.

Comment: and what means for binary rejected should i upload new build?

Comment: I believe that if your binary is rejected then you need to upload a new build.  Only if it is "metadata rejected" can you resubmit the same build.

Comment: From which XCode version you have uploaded app

Comment: my xcode version is 10.1

Comment: I received call from Apple and I asked him what is the difference between binary and metadata rejected, he said when app in metadata rejected state you need to change app description privacy policy line screenshot etc, but when in binary you don't need to edit anything in app store connect just reply message and wait for next command from apple.

I want to share with you guys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about compliance with a 3rd party app store should be directed to the app store support.

Answer (score 5):

Just reply in the resolution center that you confirm that your app does not violate any of those guidelines and they will proceed with review. No need to do anything else, until further notice from apple. This has happened to me a couple of times already.

Comment: ok i’m sending you message, and will inform you guys